# How change the duration of a React-Native timing animation dynamically?

Tags: react-native

I want to know if, once you create a `timing` Animation in React-Native and start it, can you can update its duration dynamically, without having to stop/recreate the animation? This is the use case that motivated this question:

I am developing a music player in React-Native. I have a simple Player component with a progress bar (slider) like this:

[image]

Basically, an `Animated.Value` is used as the slider's value. When pressing play, a `timing` animation starts, its duration being the duration of the song. Simultaneously, I control the timers with `setInterval()`. Every 1000 milliseconds, I add +1 to the timer displayed.

This works fine. Here I have a [simple Expo snackbar](https://snack.expo.io/@hectorricardo/myplayer) showing how this works.

The problem is, I want to add a slider that controls the playback speed:

[image]

let's ignore the real audio playback and focus only on the slider and timers behavior. If the playback is paused, then when sliding the "Speed factor" slider, it's a very easy change because I only need to update the timers. The progress bar stays the same. But when we're currently playing the song, how do I handle the updates of the timers and the progress bar?

The speed factor slider will adjust the real duration of the song with this formula:

`real_duration = normal_duration / speed_factor` where `speed_factor` can be a number between 0.5 and 1.5, for example.

And due to this change duration, I ask whether it is possible to update on the fly an animation's duration, once it has started.

Comment: did you find how to solve this?